# Settings and Livepatch option not working under Software & Updates after upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: package-management, updates, software-center

I upgraded 2 days ago from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04. After that when I open Software & Updates, either from GUI or cli (using update-manager command) it runs fine and at the end it says: `The software on this computer is up to date`. I have then the option for "Settings and Livepatch...". When I click on it nothing appears, but in the terminal I receive the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module> app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)   
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 254, in __init__self.init_ubuntu_pro()   
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 1661, in init_ubuntu_pro self.ubuntu_pro_page = UbuntuProPage(self)  
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/UbuntuProPage.py", line 83, in __init__ubuntu_pro_logo = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_scale(os.path.join(parent.datadir, 'ubuntu-pro-logo.svg'), -1, 50, True)  
gi.repository.GLib.GError:
    gdk-pixbuf-error-quark: Couldn't recognize the image file format  
    for file "/usr/share/software-properties/ubuntu-pro-logo.svg" (3)
```

The file is present and file type seems correct.

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/software-properties/ubuntu-pro-logo.svg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4989 gen 20 11:58 /usr/share/software-properties/ubuntu-pro-logo.svg
```

```
$ file /usr/share/software-properties/ubuntu-pro-logo.svg
/usr/share/software-properties/ubuntu-pro-logo.svg: SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image
```

[image: Screenshot of operation]

Do you have any suggestion about what to check?

Comment: Is it possible there's a package missing. Try `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^` (the caret is important) - which will put back anything that went astray in the upgrade.

Comment: Run the command, but no positive effect, same error. Furthermore libreoffice was reinstalled, but it's a minor issue. Any further suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, no. I clean installed Ubuntu 20.04 and upgraded to 22.04. It all works fine. I wonder if there's a mime problem. Can you try `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime` and `sudo /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache`. Then try again?

Comment: I found no /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf directory. How can I check and install it?

Comment: Apologies, I got the folder name wrong. it's `sudo /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache`

Comment: Solved, window opened. Many thanks

Comment: Is there a way to set the discussion as Solved?

Comment: Excellent! I've turned my comment into an answer, you can mark that as useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this happens, you can often resolve it by regenerating mime caches with these two commands:

`sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime`
and

`sudo /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache`